# Exporting a Static Haskell Library using Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Suppose one is using the Stack build tool to make a Haskell library (with external dependencies from Hackage). I understand how to build a Haskell program using `stack build` which can be used to execute the Haskell's `Main` function.

**Question:** But how does one export a single static library (i.e., a single `*.o` or `*.so`) -- that includes ALL of the dependencies of the project -- to be consumed by another ghc program?